# When should I pass a "reference to pointer" or a "pointer to pointer" rather then just a pointer to the function?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have been trying to implement [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) for 2D data points using C++.

My `Node` struct is as follow (here, each 2D point is in form of `std::vector<float> point`. So, point[0] would be `x` and `point[1]` would be `y`. Also, each `node` have some sort of `id`.):

```
struct Node {
    std::vector<float> point;
    int id;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node(std::vector<float> setPoint, int setId)
        : point(setPoint), id(setId), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
```

Here is my `KdTree` struct:

```
struct KdTree {
    Node* root;

     KdTree() : root(NULL) {}

    void insertHelper(Node* node, int depth, std::vector<float> point, int id) {
        if(node == NULL) {
            node = new Node(point, id);
            return;
        }

        uint currDim = depth % 2;

        if(point[currDim] < node->point[currDim])
            insertHelper(node->left, depth + 1, point, id);
        else
            insertHelper(node->right, depth + 1, point, id);
    }

    void insert(std::vector<float> point, int id) {
        insertHelper(root, 0, point, id);
    }

    void printKdTreeHelper(Node* node) {
        if(node == NULL) 
            return;

        std::cout << node->id << ": (" << node->point[0] << ", " << node->point[1] << ")\n";
        printKdTreeHelper(node->left);
        printKdTreeHelper(node->right);
    }

    void printKdTree() {
        printKdTreeHelper(root);
    }
};
```

and here is `main`:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> points = {{-6.2, 7}, {-6.3, 8.4}, {-5.2, 7.1}, {-5.7, 6.3}};

    KdTree* tree = new KdTree;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
        tree->insert(points[i], i);
    
    tree->printKdTree();
}
```

So, basically, I have been trying to `insert` points in `tree` and then print the `tree`. But nothing is being printed.

The biggest confusion I have is that in the `insertHelper` function if I update `Node*` (**pointer**) to `Node*&` (**a reference to pointer**) then everything works as expected i.e. `void insertHelper(Node* node ...)` does not work but `void insertHelper(Node*& node ...)` works. I kind of got it but still, it's not quite/crystal clear. I mean through `Node*` I'm already passing a pointer to the function, so whatever I do in the function should reflect in `main` as well, right? After all, I'm passing a pointer not a variable by value, isn't it? Why there is a need of passing a reference to pointer -- `Node*&`?

In fact, somewhere I also found another solution: pass by a pointer to pointer i.e. `void insertHelper(Node** node ...)` and then deference it in the function body. However, that doesn't make sense to me either.

While answering this question, if possible, please share further resources and/or references I can take a look into to improve my understanding.

PS: I came already across some SO QnA on **a reference to pointer** but I couldn't correlate with any of them in the context of above problem/confusion!

Comment: If you pass an argument _by value_, you (basically) work with the copy of the argument. If you pass it _by reference_, you work with the argument itself. Whether an argument is a pointer or not does not matter at all.

Comment: @DanielLangr thanks for your comment but sorry, I'm still somewhat confused: here `Node*` is a pointer to the `Node` object which is on the heap, right? So, doesn't it make any difference? In that case, what's the difference between passing the `Node` object itself v/s passing a pointer to that object `Node*` (except the fact that if the object is very big then there would be more copy w.r.t. copying a pointer) ?

Comment: The object on the heap doesn't matter. What matters is whether you need to update the pointer. If you need to update the pointer in the function, you need to pass it by reference. If you pass it by value, you update the copy of that pointer instead.

Comment: @DanielLangr I think now it makes more sense to me. Thanks again for clarifying & for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

> When should I pass a “reference to pointer” or a “pointer to pointer” rather then just a pointer to the function?

You can use indirection to modify a variable outside the function. Thus, if you want to modify a pointer, then you can pass a pointer or a reference to that pointer into a function which can then modify that referred pointer. For example:

```
Node* some_ptr;

void foo(Ptr*& ptr) {
    ptr = some_ptr;
}

Node* ptr;
foo(ptr);
```

Typically however a preferable alternative is to instead return the new value, and assign it to a variable:

```
Node* foo() {
    return some_ptr;
}

Node* ptr = foo();
```

Comment: By **indirection** you meant pointer & reference, right? Also, thanks a lot for your time and for giving this concise & easy-to-understand answer! (Sincere apologies for the late reply from my end)

Comment: @Milan Yes, pointers and references are forms of indirection. There are more abstract forms of indirection such as iterators, but internally they are implemented with one of those two. If you find the answer helpful, you can mark it accepted.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again @eerorika for clarifying. Actually, before marking this answer as accepted, I thought I would wait for some more days in case someone else also posts his/her answer. But yes, I did upvote your answer :)